# MySQL & Rails 4 - bundle exec rake db:migrate - Unsupported database for migration to UTF-8

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, bundler, dbmigrate

I have a Ruby on Rails 4 app that I have cloned from Github and am trying to get up and running on my MacBook in a dev environment.

Initially the app complained about not finding MySQL, so I did `brew install mysql`.  I now have `mysqld` running with username `root` and no password and the app is able to connect to it, so I got past the first hump.

The schema hasn't been built in the database yet, though -- and I can see about 115 files in the `db/migrate/` directory with names like `004_make_unicode_fiendly.rb` and `016_add_asin_column.rb`.

I tried to run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, but I got an error after the first three migration files apparently ran successfully:

```
Migration error: Unsupported database for migration to UTF-8 support
/Users/jon/work/amazing_app/db/migrate/004_make_unicode_friendly.rb:22:in `alter_database_and_tables_charsets'
/Users/jon/work/amazing_app/db/migrate/004_make_unicode_friendly.rb:3:in `up'
```

running `mysqladmin variables | grep utf8` shows:

```
| character_set_client                               | utf8
| character_set_connection                           | utf8
| character_set_database                             | utf8
| character_set_results                              | utf8
| character_set_server                               | utf8
| character_set_system                               | utf8
| collation_connection                               | utf8_general_ci
| collation_database                                 | utf8_general_ci
| collation_server                                   | utf8_general_ci
```

My question: why am I getting a migration error here?

Comment: Could you try running (bundle exec) rake db:create (if the DB has not already been created), and rake db:reset?

Comment: Also, if that's not a solution, could you please make the 004_make_unicode_friendly.rb file available so we can look at it further (github gist or pastebin)

Comment: Thanks - I just issued the following three commands in order and now things seem to work: `bundle exec rake db:create` `bundle exec rake db:reset` `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer as discussed:
 - Execute (bundle exec rake) db:create, db:reset

This will create the DB using your seeds and schema as they are on the other machine. Not knowing the specific error details I can't comment on why you received the error in the first place (unless it's saying you can't migrate to UTF-8 because you *already* are on UTF-8).

FYI that DB:Migrate should not be necessary unless your existing code base had an pending migration.